# Jekyll assigns all blog posts with the category 'blog'

Tags: jekyll

Jekyll assigns all blog posts with the category 'blog': Is this the default behaviour?

When i list all categories with their post count, it shows that all blog posts have been assigned with the category 'blog' and the category I applied.

So for example:

- blog (10)
- design (4)
- development (6)

I'd like to remove the 'blog' category.

Repository: https://github.com/franzos/dkkma

Comment: And your code repository url can be useful.

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for the tip. I'm just getting started with Jekyll. I've added the git repository to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your posts are in `blog/_posts` they are attributed the blog category.

Moving all your posts from `blog/_posts` to `_posts` will resolve your problem.

As you have `permalink: /blog/entry/:title` no change is made to urls.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks! :)